# Android Studio 3.0 rc2: Android Device Monitor failed to open

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-device-monitor

I've recently updated my Android Studio to 3.0 rc2 using Beta channel of the update section inside the application.

Today I wanted to use Android Device Monitor where an exception happened and saved to log inside sdk folder.

The log is this:

```
!SESSION 2017-10-28 19:28:26.756 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-28 19:28:27.267
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @4abdb505
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findAddURLMethod(BaseStorage.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.<init>(BaseStorage.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator.addHooks(BaseHookConfigurator.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.loadConfigurators(HookRegistry.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.initialize(HookRegistry.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.<init>(BaseAdaptor.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.createAdaptor(EclipseStarter.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-28 19:28:27.309
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I don't know how to handle this error and I need a way around.
I'll be glad with any suggestion to solve it without mentioning "download stable version" and downgrade.

**UPDATE:** After I tried to update to Stable version through the Stable channel of update section I get error that some files missing

```
gradle/m2repository/com/android/java/
gradle/m2repository/com/android/java/tools/
gradle/m2repository/com/android/java/tools/build/
gradle/m2repository/com/android/java/tools/build/java-lib-model-builder/
gradle/m2repository/com/android/java/tools/build/java-lib-model/
```

I'm trying to update every single module so maybe I could solve this issue

**UPDATE-2:** After cancelling previous error and running the Android Studio, It seems to be updated but the error is still there, here is the error after updating to Stable version:

```
!SESSION 2017-10-28 19:55:04.560 -------------------------------------------
----
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-28 19:55:04.922
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @4abdb505
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findAddURLMethod(BaseStorage.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.<init>(BaseStorage.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator.addHooks(BaseHookConfigurator.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.loadConfigurators(HookRegistry.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.initialize(HookRegistry.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.<init>(BaseAdaptor.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.createAdaptor(EclipseStarter.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-28 19:55:04.959
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

**UPDATE-3:** After A LOT of searching, I found a solution but it's not the answer so I added this update to question.

I can run the Android device monitor manually by going to `/sdk/tools/` and run the `monitor.bat` file by cmd or powershell and now I have access to this feature, but even now, the Android Studio can't open it for me!!!!
Please if anyone can help me post an answer telling me a workaround this problem.

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 Stable is released a couple of days ago, try to update and check if the issue still persists

Comment: @OmarAlHalabi you mean from the Stable channel of update section?! I checked just yesterday, I'll update the question if I could update to stable version

Comment: @OmarAlHalabi I couldn't update to stable version due to some conflict, I updated to question regarding this issue!

Comment: @OmarAlHalabi I think the app updated! I don't know how! but the problem is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of try and catch! I finally fixed the issue.
Android Studio 3.0 is not fully support JDK 9
After installing JDK 8 on my system and set it as JAVA_HOME variable and restarting the system everything is working now.
I got it because I wanted to install Nativescript and I couldn't cause it only supports JDK 8. that was my first clue

Set JAVA_HOME variable to JDK 8 directory and everything will be okay

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows try opening your Android Studio in Administrative Mode (Run as administrator)

Comment: I did read the other page recomending this option, nothing happened and the problem occured even then